# Given that β and γ are in S4 with βγ=(1432), γβ=(1243), and β(1)=4, determine β and γ.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve this using function composition but I don't know how to progress because all we know is β(1)=4.

Comment: Does βγ=(1432) mean that β(γ(1))=1, β(γ(2))=4, β(γ(3))=3, and β(γ(4))=2?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Try to find that $\gamma(4)=2$ and $\beta(2)=3$ and $\gamma(3)=4$ and $\gamma(1)=1$  and $\beta(3)=1$ and $\beta(4)=2$ and $\gamma(2)=3$

For example to find $\gamma(4)=2$: we have $\gamma\beta(1)=\gamma(4)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is exercise 56 in chapter 5 of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

To find $\beta$ and $\gamma$ you can repeatedly use $\beta \gamma$ and $\gamma \beta$ as follows:

(1) $\beta (1) = 4$ and $\gamma \beta (1) = 2$ implies $\gamma (4) = 2$.

(2) $\gamma (4) = 2$ and $\beta \gamma (4) = 3$ implies $\beta (2) = 3$.

(3) $\beta (2) = 3$ and $\gamma \beta (2) = 4$ implies $\gamma (3) = 4$.

(4) $\gamma (3) = 4$ and $\beta \gamma (3) = 2$ implies $\beta (4) = 2$.

(5) $\beta (4) = 2$ and $\gamma \beta (4) = 3$ implies $\gamma (2) = 3$.

(6) $\gamma (2) = 3$ and $\beta \gamma (2) =1$ implies $\beta (3) = 1$.

Hence $\beta = (1423)$.

(7) $\beta (3) = 1$ and $\gamma \beta (3) = 1$ implies $\gamma (1) = 1$ hence $\gamma = (234)$.

Answer (score 0):

Besides to Sami's theoretical approach you may find them computationally as follows:

```
gap> g:=SymmetricGroup(4);
     e:=Elements(g);
     for i in [1..Size(e)] do
        for j in [1..Size(e)] do
           if e[i]*e[j]=e[19] and e[j]*e[i]=e[11] then Print("Beta=",e[i],"  ", "Gamma=",e[j],"\n");
           fi;
        od;
      od;
```

---

```
 Beta=(2,3,4)  Gamma=(1,4,2,3)
 Beta=(1,2)  Gamma=(2,4,3)
 Beta=(1,3,2,4)  Gamma=(1,3,4)
 Beta=(1,4,3)  Gamma=(1,2)
```

Comment: GAP to the rescue! 8)

Comment: Thanks. How r u Amy? Have those unwanted problems been solved? I hope they have.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: But it is under the light of yours Sami. :)